# Style the archives/category sidebar widget via theme

Tags: themes, widgets, css

I would like to change the appearance of the categories and archives widgets in the sidebar such that each category/month alternates the row color. The only way I know how to accomplish this requires modifying the PHP code in the core that generates the category and archives widgets (outputting alternating css styles depending on odd/even rows). I want to avoid modifying core files and instead do everything in the theme. Is there a way to accomplish this even/odd row styling for these widgets from within the theme or via CSS only?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo-class:

```
li:nth-child(odd){ 
  background-color: white;
}

li:nth-child(even){
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I know how to accomplish this requires modifying the PHP code in the core that generates the category and archives widgets (outputting alternating css styles depending on odd/even rows).

If you can't do it in CSS, don't edit the core. Copy the core widget's code and create your own widget.

By the way, I really like [One Trick Pony's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1986/one-trick-pony) solution (+1) but it is a CSS3 solution which I still do not trust. ( A quick look around suggests that IE8 does not support `nth-child` ) We are getting close to acceptable support though. I am waiting for the day...